# add parent's id to appended clone's while appending renamed clones to multiple parents

Tags: jquery, attributes, append, clone, parent-child

Is it possible to clone a single element, append it to many elements, and add each new parent's respective id to each new respective clone's all on one line of jQuery?

I can clone and append, but I don't know how to grab the id of the element being appended to.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
$(".myClass tr td:last-child").append($("#elementToClone").clone(false).attr('id',$(this).attr('id') + ?));
```

Where `?` is where I'm lost.

Many thanks in advance!

**Few-liners Welcome**

Didn't know that could be a possibility, but 1 is better than 2 or 3.  Few-liner can get a check until a 1 liner comes along.

Comment: It can definitely be done but I'll stick my neck out and say, no, not in one line.

Comment: Why on earth would you need a one-liner, when two, three and even four liners works just as well. It's just nonsense to try and fit everything in one line.

Comment: @adeneo Few-liner's good enuf for me.  Can you answer with that?

Comment: *all in one line* is good only when it is easy to read and maintain.. If not, write in separate lines until it is easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but maybe it's this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6jXb4/)

Comment: A better solution IMO would be this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6jXb4/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If with parents id you mean the id of the `td` (*and for some reason you want to avoid manual variable creations*) then you can

```
$(".myClass tr td:last-child").each(function(index, element) {
    $("#elementToClone").clone(false).attr('id', function(i, value) {
        return value + element.id;
    }).appendTo(element);
});
```

---

In regards to a single liner, the above can easily become

```
$(".myClass tr td:last-child").each(function(index, element) {$("#elementToClone").clone(false).attr('id', function(i, value) {return value + element.id;}).appendTo(element);});
```

Which is exactly the same code without the whitespace.. (*not sure why you give gravity to it though..*)

Comment: meant "single chain" (which this qualifies imo).  gotta work on my vocab sloppiness...

Comment: better than manually adding `elementToClone` over and over and over and...to the actual html page ;))  Great solution!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".myClass tr td:last-child").each(function() {
    var $clone = $("#elementToClone").clone(false);
    $clone.attr('id', $clone.attr('id') + $(this).attr('id')).appendTo(this);
});
```

*untested*